# How can I make the text adjacent to my checkbox clickable in php

Tags: php, html

how can I make users check on textclick? My script is:

```
 <?php 
      foreach($getcountry_name as $key => $value)
 { ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="25" valign="top">
        <input name="country_name[]"  
             type="checkbox" checked="checked" 
             value="<?php echo $value['country_id']; ?>" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <label class="type01"><?php echo $value['country_name']; ?></label>
        </td>
    </tr> 
   <?php
     }
   ?>
```

thanks in  advance

Answer (score 5):

The `<label>` needs a `for` attribute that contains the ID of the `<input>` field it's linked to.

e.g.

```
<input id="myID" name="country_name[]"  type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $value['country_id']; ?>" />
<label for="myID" class="type01"><?php echo $value['country_name']; ?></label>
```

**Edit:**

Applying it to your example,

```
<?php 
      foreach($getcountry_name as $key => $value)
 { ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="25" valign="top">
        <input id="country_name_<?php echo $value['country_id']; ?>" name="country_name[]"  
             type="checkbox" checked="checked" 
             value="<?php echo $value['country_id']; ?>" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <label for="country_name_<?php echo $value['country_id']; ?>" class="type01"><?php echo $value['country_name']; ?></label>
        </td>
    </tr> 
   <?php
     }
   ?>
```

Comment: Note that one can do it implicitly as well by wrapping the checkbox in the label: <label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" />Clickable text goes here</label>. Do note that it's deprecated as of some XHTML version (can't remember which)

Comment: @antennen ... and not possible across table cells.

Comment: @antennen: Which only matters if you use XHTML, which most people don't (although it appears the OP is, from the end of their input tag). It's fine in HTML, right up through HTML5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-label-element  Not for every situation (as jensgram points out), but...

Answer (score 0):

Give the `input`an ID and let your `label` use this as the value for a `for` attribute.

---

```
<tr>
    <td width="25" valign="top">
        <input id="<?php $id=uniqid('id_'); echo $id; ?>" name="country_name[]" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $value['country_id']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="type01"><?php echo $value['country_name']; ?></label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hmm .. yeah, you can probably just use the `country_id` if it qualifies for a HTML ID. ... or the `$key` from the newly edited `for` loop :)